# unrecognized arguments: --location while creating the Azure Mysql Flexi -Server Replica create

Tags: azure, azure-mysql-database

The requirement is to implement Cross-region replication using Azure MySQL Flexi server DB. From the Azure portal, have the option to choose a location while creating the replica.
[image]

The same replica creation we are trying to achieve via commands, getting the below issue. The source server is in the west region, would like to create a replica in the east region.

**Note:** Both primary and secondary servers are in the same RG.

> az mysql flexible-server replica create --replica-name az-flexi-master-west-dr -g primary-DB --source-server az-flexi-master --location eastus

```
unrecognized arguments: --location eastus
```

followed this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/mysql/flexible-server/replica?view=azure-cli-latest

Do we have the possibility to provide a location argument while creating the Azure mysql Flexi server replica?

Comment: Yes, you can provide `--location` argument while creating Azure MySQL Flexi server replica. Same command worked for me, check [this](https://i.imgur.com/qVE5rL9.png)

Comment: @sridevi, Thanks for the quick response. Did you set any default location before creatin g the replica?

Comment: No, I did n't set any default location

Comment: OK, what is the AZ CLI version you are using? As per the following document, will it allow the replica creation in the same location as the source server? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/how-to-read-replicas-cli

Comment: I'm using AZ CLI **2.51.0** version, check [this](https://i.imgur.com/aT3Ao2E.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, it's possible to provide `--location` argument while creating Azure MySQL Flexible Server Replica. You can also create replica in the **same location** as the source server.

I created one Azure MySQL Flexible Server with **same properties** as you in **`West US`** location like this:

[image]

To create Azure MySQL Flexible Server **Replica** in above server via CLI, I ran same command with `--location` argument and got **response** like this:

```
az mysql flexible-server replica create --replica-name az-flexi-master-west-dr -g primary-DB --source-server az-flexi-master --location eastus
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where replica created successfully in **East US** location:

[image]

When I checked the resource group, it has both servers with `East US` and `West US` locations:

[image]

To check the installed version of Azure CLI, you can use **`az version`** command:

[image]

In your case, check what **CLI version** you are currently using and upgrade it to **latest** version by running **`az upgrade`** command.

When I tried to create replica in **same location** as the source server, it created successfully like below:

```
az mysql flexible-server replica create --replica-name az-flexi-master-west-dr -g primary-DB --source-server az-flexi-master1 --location westus
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[az mysql flexible-server replica | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/mysql/flexible-server/replica?view=azure-cli-latest#az-mysql-flexible-server-replica-create-optional-parameters)

Comment: az mysql flexible-server replica create: Add --location to support specifying replica location in az cli version 2.50.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/release-notes-azure-cli#rdbms